# USB stick cannot be formatted to F2FS

Tags: usb-flash-drive, format

I have a 16GB USB stick which I want to format to `f2fs`. On Linux, the format command itself can succeed. <strike>However, if I try to copy files to that stick, I got IO error.</strike> However, I can not mount it.

But the same stick works fine when formatted into other formats, say `vfat` or `ext4`. So I guess my USB stick is not faulty.

Any idea what might cause the error?

## Update

I just tried again, and here's the output.

```
➜  /mnt  sudo mkfs -t f2fs /dev/sdb1

        F2FS-tools: mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.4.0 (2014-09-18)

Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 32765952 (in 512bytes)
Info: zone aligned segment0 blkaddr: 256
Info: Discarding device
Info: This device doesn't support TRIM
Info: format successful
➜  /mnt  sudo mount /dev/sdb1 usb
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
```

**Notice**: I cannot read the **superblock**, even thought the format succeed.

## Update 2

I tried to do `fsck`, and I got

```
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 32765952 (in 512bytes)
[ASSERT] (sanity_check_nid: 225)  --> nid[0x3] blk_addr[0x3e7d00] footer.nid[0x0]

NID[0x3] is unreachable
[FSCK] Unreachable nat entries                        [Fail] [0x1]
[FSCK] SIT valid block bitmap checking                [Fail]
[FSCK] Hard link checking for regular file            [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_block_count matching with CP             [Fail] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matcing with CP (de lookup)   [Fail] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matcing with CP (nat lookup)  [Ok..] [0x1]
[FSCK] valid_inode_count matched with CP              [Fail] [0x0]
[FSCK] free segment_count matched with CP             [Ok..] [0x1f01]
[FSCK] next block offset is free                      [Ok..]
[FSCK] other corrupted bugs                           [Fail]
```

I tried to format the partition again, and still got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem formatting a usb flash drive partition with mkfs.f2fs ver 1.4.0 and using a different linux install that had mkfs.f2fs Ver: 1.4.1 installed solved it for me.

Comment: Actually, my problem is that I had a faulty thumb drive...